# Webview display different in android version for same url

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I have Loading URL in web view but api<19 its will display menu bar as menu options in that having home, headlines, and commentary etc.. like image1 and api>19 it will display like image2 in webview.  but i want display web age like image1 for all android version.

[image]
[image]

Image1                                                                    Image2

How to display url in image1 for all android api versions?

Comment: The site on the left is responsive while the site on the right doesn't seem to be. Looks like the website isn't recognizing the Android device.

Comment: Check your server logs and see what is being reported as the user agent in each case, and compare that against your server logic for deciding what content to serve. If this is not your server, then it is not your decision as to what the server serves.